# How to listen to a change in call log database?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, calllog

I have a homescreen widget which has to be notified when a missed call has come. I did this with a `ContentObserver`, but it doesn't work always and I've read that the cause is that ContentObservers must not be registered in an `AppWidgetProvider`. So I want to try to use a `BroadcastReceiver`. I've made successfully a calendar changes listener that gets notified each time I add, delete or modify an event in the calendar. I did it in this way:

```
<receiver
    android:name="...backend.observers.CalendarChangesReceiver"
>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I tried to use the above approach to listen to changes in the call log database but it didn't worked. The question is, why? The code is shown below.

My question has not been answered yet in Stackoverflow.
I can not register a receiver to the action `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` because I do not only want to listen to a new missed call but also I want my application to get notified when the missed call is read by the user. `PROVIDER_CHANGED` should be useful to achieve this, but `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is useless to do this.

```
<receiver
    android:name="...backend.observers.CallsChangesReceiver"
>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:host="com.android.phone"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: The same code for calendar is not working for me. How did you do that? Are you using Service along with BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Calendar works for me with that code, but not phone. Finally for phone I used a broadcast receiver who gets noticed when a call enters.